# Register indirect addressing

Tags: assembly, masm, x86-16

I would like to know if there is a difference between:

```
MOV [BX] + 20, AX
```

and

```
MOV [BX + 20], AX
```

My reasoning is that for the 1st case, we move the value of `AX + 20` into the address `BX`

And for the 2nd case, we move the value of `AX` into the address `BX+ 20`

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Some assembler compilers allow both combinations.
However, the debugger should give you right answer!

```
Test.asm.5: MOV [BX] + 20, AX
004552B4 894314           mov [bx+$14],ax
Test.asm.6: MOV [BX + 20], AX
004552B7 894314           mov [bx+$14],ax
```

Answer (score 1):

Your reasoning on the first case is wrong.  That's not a valid construct (unless you have a macro defined to turn it into 2 instructions).  You can't stick a value ADD in the middle of a MOV.  You can only use the immediate offset to the address (second case).